# Sharing Excel multi cell array selection bewteen workbooks in real time

Tags: arrays, excel, real-time, sharing

I have a workbook that has an add-in to update values from SQL database in real time (using RTD server). 
Now I need to be able to select the range of cells (user selection) from the master workbook and store this value somehow using unique ID label for the particular selection to be able to retrieve the unique selection to other workbooks. Any suggestion on this please? 
RTD cannot handle array (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286258). I was thinking about creating csv files labelled by ID and then linked them using data link connection.